# Why the functional interface is not implemented by the class?

Tags: java, lambda, interface, functional-programming, composition

I saw the following code in a tutorial. My question is why the interface Drawable is not implemented by the class LambdaExpressionExample2? I am familiar with composition between classes. Is that the case here as well ? Thank you.

```
@FunctionalInterface  //It is optional  
interface Drawable{  
    public void draw();  
}  
  
public class LambdaExpressionExample2 {  
    public static void main(String[] args) {  
        int width=10;  
          
        //with lambda  
        Drawable d2=()->{  
            System.out.println("Drawing "+width);  
        };  
        d2.draw();  
    }  
}
```

Comment: If `LambdaExpressionExample2` implemented the interface (instead of the lambda expression), then it wouldn't be an example of a lambda expression, which presumably is the point of the code.

Comment: Because 1. `LambdaExpressionExample2` doesn't have a `draw` method. 2. You don't see `LambdaExpressionExample2 implements Drawable`

Comment: `LambdaExpressionExample2` is just the main class, i.e. the entry point of your code (every Java program needs such an entry point). So it is not related to the functional interface.

Answer (score 1):

You can implement in main class also:

```
public class LambdaExpressionExample2 implements Drawable{

    @Override
    public void draw() {
        System.out.println("Implemented it in main class !!!");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        LambdaExpressionExample2 lm = new LambdaExpressionExample2();
        lm.draw();

    }

 }
```

But that won't be lambda.

Or you can define another implementation like :

```
public class DrawableImpl implements Drawable {
    @Override
    public void draw() {

        System.out.println("I have implemented Drawable !!!");

    }
}

public class LambdaExpressionExample2{

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        DrawableImpl dm = new DrawableImpl();
        dm.draw();

    }

    }
```

But that is also not lambda.
You can also use anonymous class as below (old style):

```
public class LambdaExpressionExample2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Drawable anonymus_class = new Drawable() {
            @Override
            public void draw() {
                System.out.println("Anonymus class");
            }

        };
        anonymus_class.draw();
    }
}
```

If you compare all, you will see lambda notation is most precise and intuitive.

Comment: Thanks all. So is this a rule that in order to use Lambda expression, the functional interface is not implemented in the class?

Comment: From Wiki - "In computer programming, an anonymous function (function literal, lambda abstraction, or lambda expression) is a function definition that is not bound to an identifier. " So, the codes in my examples are not lambda. When you use lambda, you just create, use and throw it away once done.

Comment: Understood. My confusion is regarding class signature. Usually when a class is working with an interface its signature look like this, for example: "public class abc implements xyz". But in examples the "implements" key word is missing and I was wondering why class is not implementing the interface using implements key word.

Answer (score 0):

The interface is used for the lambda function itself, not the `LambdaExpressionExample2` class.

To see what I mean let's have a look at other ways you could achieve this functionality.

1. Instead of using a lambda, you could use an anonymous inner class. Before lambda functions became a thing in Java 8, this is how you would have had to do it.

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int width=10;

    // with anonymous inner class
    Drawable d1 = new Drawable() {
        @Override
        public void draw() {
            System.out.println("Anonymous Class: Drawing " + width);
        }
    };

    d1.draw();
}
```

Here you can see the anonymous class is implementing the `Drawable` interface, by providing an implementation for the `draw` method.

2. We could use a concrete class that implements the `Drawable` interface

```java
@FunctionalInterface  
interface Drawable{
    public void draw();
}

class ConcreteDrawable implements Drawable {
    @Override
    public void draw() {
        System.out.println("Concrete Class: Drawing");
    }
}

public class LambdaExpressionExample2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // with concrete class
        Drawable d1 = new ConcreteDrawable();
        d1.draw();
    }
}
```

In this example, we no longer have access to the local `width` variable in the draw method. But you can see that the `ConcreteDrawable` class also provides an implementation of the `Drawable` interface.

3. Or finally we can use a lambda function.

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int width = 10;
    
    // with lambda
    Drawable d1 = () -> { System.out.println("Lambda: Drawing " + width); };
    
    d1.draw();
}
```

Here the lambda function is implementing the `Drawable` interface, by giving an implementation of the `draw` method. The only reason why we can use a lambda function here is that the `Drawable` interface only declares one method.

So in summary, it is not the `LambdaExpressionExample2` class that should implement `Drawable` but instead the lambda function itself.